# How to combine the UItabbar and navigationcontroller without using UItabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing on applocation.In that i want to use the UITabbar and navigation controller.Because every tab in the tabbar contain the back and save buttons for saving that tab information and coming back.So i want use the both UItabbar and navigationcontroller.Please tell me how to use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [step-by-step tutorial with images](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/).